# In how many ways can a team of 5 people be chosen from the group if the team includes at least two boys and at least one girl?

Tags: combinatorics

> A group has twelve people, consisting of three boys, four girls and five adults. In how many ways can a team of 5 people be chosen from the group if the team includes at least two boys and at least one girl?

Here's my understanding.

We can first select two boys and 1 girls. This can be done in $3C2×4C1$ ways as we are selecting 2 boys from the 3 and 1 girl from the 4.

As we have now met the condition above, we just need to select two people from the remaining 9. This is $9C2$. As such the number of ways is $$3C2×4C1×9C2$$

However this is wrong. The solutions solve this by listing cases and finding the number of ways for each one.

So what is actually wrong with my method above? Is there overcounting of some cases somewhere?

Comment: In the problem statement you say "two boys" twice. Was the first time supposed to be "three boys"? That would make the numbers of people actually add up to $12$.

Comment: Sorry about that. It was suppose to say "three boys"

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73969/139123, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4443589/139123, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4509863/139123, and other similar questions and their answers. This is a very frequent error.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that there is more than one girl in the team of $5$ people. These groups will be counted multiple times, once for each girl being the "first girl".